# Server response contains invalid xml

Tags: xml, exchangewebservices

When calling the SendAndSaveCopy method in EWS, I get an error that the server response returns invalid xml.

I have plowed through several pages of EWS documentation but haven't been able to turn anything up.  I tried enabling trace flags, but only the html for the .asmx page shows.

How can I fix this?

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri("http://mex07a.emailsrvr.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myname@mydomain.com", "mypassword","mydomain.com");

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = "Interesting";
message.Body = "The proposition has been considered.";
message.ToRecipients.Add("name@mail.com");
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Note: The "http://mex07a.emailsrvr.com/ews/Exchange.asmx" link has been verified, as it directly to my email page.

Comment: A place to start would be to enable tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx and look at the SOAP request and responses.

Comment: When I try enabling tracing, I just get the html of the .asmx page.

Comment: That sounds like you have problems with EWS itself maybe you want to do some testing with something like the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/